# Database_cleaner gem isn't cleaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec

I'm using Mongoid as my database and have configured my `spec_helper.rb` file as instructed on other Stackoverflow questions, however I'm still getting an error that the Object exists on subsequent tests.  So, `database_cleaner` isn't cleaning my test db as it should.

Here is my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rails/mongoid'
require 'mongoid-rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'

Mongoid.load!(Rails.root.join("config", "mongoid.yml"))

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  #config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

And my rspec test file is simple:

```
describe Stock do
  it "should get created with only name and symbol" do
    stock = Stock.create(name: "Netflix", symbol: "NFLX")
    expect(stock.errors.full_messages).to eq []
  end
end
```

The output I'm getting is fine on first run (after I manually reset the db) with `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test` however every run after that I am getting:

```
Failures:

  1) Stock should get created with only name and symbol
     Failure/Error: expect(stock.errors.full_messages).to eq []

       expected: []
            got: ["Symbol is already taken"]

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/stock_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Well, after alot more reading, I've come to determine that database_cleaner and Mongo aren't playing well together.  While it's probably not the cleanest solution, it is simple:

In my `spec_helper.rb` file, I ended up adding this line to the `RSpec.configure` block:

```
config.after(:each) do
  Mongoid.purge!
end
```

Comment: Yep, I agree. For this use case a one-line Mongoid command is better than a gem.